# Prove $f(x)= 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ is not integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I want to prove that

> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ for } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
> 0 \text{ for } x \notin \mathbb{Q}
> \end{cases}$$
>   is not integrable on $[0,1]$.

Now I'm at the point in the book where we have just learned about Riemann integrability, with partitions. So far, this is the definition we have used:

> A function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable if
>   $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists P: \overline{S}-\underline{S} < \epsilon,$$
>   where $P$ is a partition of the interval and $\overline{S}$ and $\underline{S}$ are upper and lower sums of the function.

Now if I'm right, I need to prove
$$\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall P: \overline{S}-\underline{S} > \epsilon,$$
in order to establish that the function is indeed not integrable. And this is where I'm struggling. I have the idea that, although the interval itself is bounded, the number of $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ in $[0,1]$ is not bounded. Then how could I ever choose a $\epsilon$ such that all partitions result in a larger difference? If on the other hand the number would have been finitie, say $n$, I would let $\epsilon > n \cdot 1 = n$ and then all partitions would meet this criteria (at least, I think).

Any suggestions?

Comment: As an aside, this function *is* integrable if you were talking about Lebesgue integration and results in zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that function, each superior sum is equal to $1$, and each inferior sum is equal to $0$. Therefore, take any $\varepsilon\in(0,1]$.

Comment: I would say I can make a partition where each $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is in its own interval, therefore creating infinitely many intervals with a supremum of $1$ and then the sum would be unbounded, right?

Comment: @Mathbeginner a partition in this context has finitely many divisions by definition

Comment: I don't know what that even means. What I wrote was that, for **every** partition, its superior sum is $1$ and its inferior sum is $0$. And no partition creates infinitely many intervals.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. I didn't rightfully take the length of each interval into account. I just saw that there were infinitely many points with $f(x)=1$ and therefore couldn't imagine a partition where this total sum would equal $1$. But obviously, since the intervals get smaller and smaller, the product of $1$ with this interval gets smaller as well. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

On the interval $[a,b] $,all the upper Riemann sums are $(b-a)$ and the lower Riemann sums are zero. 
There are no sequences of upper and lower sum converging to a common limit.

Thus your function is not integrable on [a,b]